# Invalid Shell command in GitHub Codespace

Tags: c, github, cs50

["C:\Users\marti\OneDrive\Pictures\Screenshots\2022-05-18 (1).png"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfDgD.png)I recently started CS50 Introduction to Computer Science. I am trying to do PSET2 readability. When I open VS Code to execute **cd**, this is what pops up in the terminal window.

```
Shell integration activated
bash: eval: -a: invalid option
eval: usage: eval [arg ...]
$
```

Please help! I am a newbie and I cannot understand what this means.

Comment: So typing cd + enter into the terminal causes this error? Doesn't really have anything to do with compiling code? But does this also happen if you do it in a normal command prompt? Also what OS are you using?

Comment: Hi, yes, you are right it about the compiling, though I did try to compile another code and the same thing popped up. it appears in a normal command prompt as well . Am using windows OS.

Comment: the error suggests you are using command `eval` with option `-a` which is not valid. can you maybe attach a screenshot?

Comment: hi ,ok let me do that

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfDgD.png

Comment: Ah, you are working in a github codespace. That is very helpful to know. I would suggest adding tags for that to this question and edit the title to `Invalid shell command in github codespace` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related to GitHub Codespace. My VSCode was misbehaving with the same `eval: -a` message.

I've bypassed this by disabling shell integration. One way to do that is by setting `terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled` to false in `settings.json`. To quickly go there, press F1 then enter `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`.